# Best way restructure object in JS

Tags: javascript, object

I have array of objects, width date and time property like below. I try restructure elements by day and time.

```
[
  {
    data: 'data1',
    date: '15-02-2020 06:00:00'
  },
  {
    data: 'data2',
    date: '15-02-2020 12:00:00'
  },
  ...
  {
    data: 'data6',
    date: '17-02-2020 07:00:00'
  },
  {
    data: 'data7',
    date: '17-02-2020 09:00:00'
  }
]
```

I want to get this:

```
{
  '15-02-2020' : {
    '06:00:00' : 'data1',
    '12:00:00' : 'data2'
  },
  '16-02-2020' : {
    '06:00:00' : 'data3',
    '12:00:00' : 'data4'
  },
  '17-02-2020' : {
    '01:00:00' : 'data5',
    '07:00:00' : 'data6',
    '09:00:00' : 'data7'
  }
}
```

I tried use `reduce`, but cant. I want do that, without temporary variables in one loop.

```
list.reduce((obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, {[item.date]: item}), {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array, split date and use the day ad key for another object.

```js
var data = [{ data: 'data1', date: '15-02-2020 06:00:00' }, { data: 'data2', date: '15-02-2020 12:00:00' }, { data: 'data6', date: '17-02-2020 07:00:00' }, { data: 'data7', date: '17-02-2020 09:00:00' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { data, date }) => {
        const [day, time] = date.split(' ');
        r[day] = r[day] || {};
        r[day][time] = data;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your array and build the result object dynamically:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    data: 'data1',
    date: '15-02-2020 06:00:00'
  },
  {
    data: 'data2',
    date: '15-02-2020 12:00:00'
  },
  {
    data: 'data6',
    date: '17-02-2020 07:00:00'
  },
  {
    data: 'data7',
    date: '17-02-2020 09:00:00'
  }
]

const res = {}

arr.forEach(item => {
  const dateArr = item.date.split(' ')
  if (res[dateArr[0]]) {
    res[dateArr[0]][dateArr[1]] = item.data
  } else {
    res[dateArr[0]] = {}
    res[dateArr[0]][dateArr[1]] = item.data
  }
})

console.log(res)
```